# How to prevent the orphan word of paragraphs

Tags: spacing

Currently, I have a paragraph in my article shown as following picture: the orphan word `MAS.` at the end of the paragraph takes a single line.
[image: Orphan word]

But somehow, there was one typeset which successfully removed the orphan word, and made the paragraph more compact, as the following picture shows: the word `Thus,` was successfully aligned itself with `location.` sentence, which results in a compact paragraph.
[image: Compact paragraph]

Unfortunately, I don't know how to control latex to reproduce this again. Could any one show me some useful skills to remove the orphan words like this?

Comment: In the first example, the reference to Figure 6(a-d) is also a problem. If this is not a automatic reference, typeset it in an `\mbox{}` *i.e*. `\mbox{Figure 6(a--d)}`, use an 'endash' in such references. If it is an automatic reference, I suggest you start using `cleveref`, which will take care of this for you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you put `\looseness=-1` immediately before the paragraph TeX will try to make it one line shorter

Comment: Or even attached to the final full stop.

Comment: @YaOzI Even though, I recommend `microtype`and `cleveref`.

Answer (score 5):

the orphan word can be avoided (though perhaps at the cost of moving something else down to the last line) by marking the last space as an unbreakable space:

```
... UCT-ObjRe~MAS.
```

(this particular example might end up with an unfortunate break after the hyphen.)

microtype can also be helpful in re-composing paragraphs.

and, as already pointed out by david carlisle, `\looseness=-1` approaches the problem from yet a different angle.